# アップロードした APK の署名が無効です

Tags: android

Google Playにアプリをアップロードしようとした際に以下のエラーが出てしまい、調べてみるとminSdkVersion と targetSdkVersion の数値に問題がある事がわかりました。
ただこの数値がわからず困っています。
どなたかアドバイスいただけませんでしょうか？

```
アップロードした APK の署名が無効です（署名の詳細）。
apksigner のエラー: ERROR (Jar signer ****.RSA): JAR signature META-INF.RSA uses/***** digest algorithm SHA-256 and signature algorithm RSA which is not supported on API Level(s) 10-17 for which this APK is being verified
```

Answer (score 1):

使用しているAPIレベルやターゲットのAndroidバージョンに応じて、`minSdkVersion`と`targetSdkVersion`にそれぞれ適切な数値をマニフェストファイルで宣言する必要があるはずです。

参考：
[<uses-sdk> | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element?hl=ja)

Comment: Android 5.0.1  API level: 21になるんですがtargetSdkVersion 21になるんでしょうか？minSdkVersionの数値はなにでわかるんでしょうか？